# how do I do a basic pusher connection to cryptsy using javascript?

Tags: javascript, api, http, bitcoin, pusher

I am trying to create a basic pusher connection to cryptsy such as https://www.cryptsy.com/pages/pushapi
Since I am receiving public data such as 'price', I should 'not' have to authenticate, only providing the cryptsy APP_KEY.
The following code fails:

```
<script src="pusher.min.js">
var pusher = new Pusher('cb65d0a7a72cd94adf1f');
var channel = pusher.subscribe('ticker.160');
channel.bind('new-price', function(data) {
  alert('An event was triggered with message: ' + data.message);
});
channel.bind('pusher:subscription_error', function(status) {
  if(status == 408 || status == 503){
    // retry?
  }
});
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?
The browser just seems to hang.
How do you create a basic pusher connection to crypsty to determine the 'new price'?

Comment: You cannot write your javascript code inside a script tag that already sources an External Javascript

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because Cryptsy no longer exists

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
<script src="//js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pusher = new Pusher("cb65d0a7a72cd94adf1f");
var channel = pusher.subscribe("ticker.160");
channel.bind("message", function(data) {
  //console.log(data);
  var topbuy = data.trade.topbuy;
  console.log("Price: ", topbuy.price,
              "Quantity:", topbuy.quantity);
});
</script>
```

After running the page, just wait for a few seconds and this will keep writing price and quantity data to Console (F12 key) for every push from the server.

Comment: same blank screen. I even tried to put it in it's own html file, same thing. permissions are 755 for dir/ , 644 for files and apache:apache (httpd recommended). no error in logs at all. tcpdump shows only port 80 traffic between client and host (I didn't check other ports)

Comment: Copy and paste the above code to a html page -> put it in your web server -> open it in your browser -> open the browser console by pressing F12 -> you will have to wait a few seconds till the pushed messages are received and then you will see the price and quantity info.

Comment: Btw, this is just a demo and prints only in the console. If you want this info for a purpose, you will have to make use of the data in a way other than just prining.

Comment: the only suspect is a bad checksum on the wire from the server  http://paste.ee/p/YlCxA